# How to convert keyword into String and keep colon

Tags: clojure

I want to replace keywords in a sql query, all of them starting with a colon, e.g. :start-date, :end-date. I'm using this bit of code:

```
(defn replace-by-pair [s [match replacement]]
  (str/replace s (re-pattern (name match)) replacement))

(replace-by-pair ":start-date" [:start-date, "20130901"])
```

Function name returns String representation of the keyword, and so the colon is not being replaced:

```
":20130901"
```

Is there another way to convert the keyword into String and include the colon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, there is another way to convert the keyword into a string - you can use `str`, like so:

```
(name :start-date)
;=> "start-date"

(str :start-date)
;=> ":start-date"
```

Comment: Couldn't see the wood for the trees.. Thanks :)